# Google calendar id max length

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I would like to know, what is maximum length of Google calendar id?
If I generate some new calendar, so it have 52 chars. Is it ever 52 chars?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: I would not rely on that. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to store it in DB and I need to know, how much chars is maximum.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer in the official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

> ```
> * the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
> * characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding,
>   i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in
>   RFC2938
> * the ID must be unique per calendar
> ```

Two last conditions are important too. I tried to create an event with 140-character length, but it failed always with the error "HttpError 400 ... Invalid resource id value." The error description is not very expainable, so the wrong length was my first thought too.

As I saw, IDs for events, which are created from Web-Interface have 26-character length. E.g. "h89br54f22543csaelbvd9bpg8".

Appeared, that I tried to put IDs with upper-case characters, which contradict another condition. I simply swiched my ID to lower case and it worked. My example is: "00000000a261a0d73f0bc4489e041b2cf89de14307003368d9e80b5c214287f8ce52b5f2ce9b000000e73a1500006036a1321a462f4a9efbc0d55b344c120000129689b50000".

The third condition snapped, when I tried to re-create the event after deletion it thought API. The event disappeared in Web-Interface, but it turned out, that calling delete() is not really deleting it, but is switching event['status'] to 'cancelled'. You can reuse the event using get() and then switching status e.g. back to 'confirmed'. BTW here I got the error "HttpError 409 ... The requested identifier already exists."