# Google Calendar API / Empty the trash of primary calendar

Tags: php, events, google-calendar-api, recycle-bin

I synchronize a calendar with an external application. I have to have the same events IDs in this application and in Google Calendar. But in this application, when an event is deleted, its ID is available for a future new event. So I'd like that, when I delete an event with Calendar API, the event's ID is available. But it always stay in the trash and I can't empty it with API.

So, the two solutions I found are:

- Use the `clear` function:

  ```
  $cld = $service->calendars->get($calendarId);
  $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getItems();
  $summary = $cld->getSummary();
  $timeZone = $cld->getTimeZone();
  $events = $service->events->listEvents("primary")->getItems();
  $service->calendars->clear('primary');
  $cld->setSummary($summary);
  $cld->setTimeZone($timeZone);
  foreach($events as $event){
      $service->events->insert("primary", $event);
  }
  ```

  But this code return message "Forbidden" with code 403 on line `$service->calendars->clear('primary');`
- Create a new calendar and make it `primary`

  ```
  $cld = $service->calendars->get($calendarId);
  $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getItems();
  $summary = $cld->getSummary();
  $timeZone = $cld->getTimeZone();
  $events = $service->events->listEvents("primary")->getItems();

  $calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
  $calendarListEntry->setId("account_mail@gmail.com");
  $calendarListEntry->setSummary($summary);
  $calendarListEntry->setTimeZone($timeZone);

  $createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

  foreach($events as $event){
      $service->events->insert("account_mail@gmail.com", $event);
  }
  ```

  But this code return message "Invalid Value" with code 400 on line `$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);`

If someone has an idea for me, it would be amazing!

**Thank you.**

Comment: what scope are you authenticating with?

Comment: I'm authenticating with the following: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`

Comment: Does your calendar ID contain uppercase letters? I'm asking because in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677229/google-calendar-id-max-length) he was to resolve the invalid value by using lower case version of the letters.

Comment: I didn't know that could be a problem, but there is no uppercase letters...

Comment: I finally don't use the same events IDs in my app and in Google Calendar. It's a bit pity, but I've got no problem. I let this post open, it could interest someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a workaround for your problem. My steps are:

1. Create a new calendar
2. Move event to the calendar
3. Delete the calendar

As far as I can see, the calendars does not have a trash...

```
$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary('calendarSummary');
$calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

$result = $service->events->move('primary', 'eventId', $createdCalendar->getId());

$service->calendars->delete($createdCalendar->getId());
```

Sorry for my poor skills on PHP

Be careful of the calendar limits (60 currently, read more about it here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)